# How To snapshot sd card memory in Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-sdcard

I want to make two snapshots in Android emulator.

The first is before running an app.

The second one is after running the app.

I want to see the following changes:

1. New files added
2. Files that have been removed
3. changes in existing files.

I tried to search a command in adb but there isn't something concrete.
I'm searching something like the program regshot but for android.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open android studio, 
1.select Android device monitor from toolbar.

2.Select your emulator from left side pane.

3.For screenshot,in left side pane selection screen-capture option(camera icon).

4. For files, select file explorer tab from right side pane.
5. Select storage option --> SdCard

I hope it helps you.

Comment: there is no option to capture the SD card memory or any memory.
only taking a screenshot - @USKMobility